# Rendering Error when adding design library

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio  on my PC (Windows 10 Home 64-bit). I want to use a floating action button for my android app and this requires the design library. When I add this library to my program, I get this error:
[Rendering error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS3aM.jpg).
The app layout also disapears.
Can you help me with this?
Thanks,
Guilherme

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Comment: Add your styles.XML. do you have a textviewStyle? Also post XML layout.